# Hashicorp Vault Snapshot Decryption

Tags: hashicorp-vault, raft

I created a snapshot of my vault server with the following command:

```
vault operator raft snapshot save snapshot.save
```

I now have a file of the snapshot, and I am able to use it to restore the server. I am trying to decrypt and read the snapshot file programmatically so that I can search for a value inside the snapshot. Is there a way to decrypt vault snapshots into plaintext ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to just decrypt it into a mysql-dump-like output file, no.
You can put it into recovery mode, then iterate thru the tree, greping for what you're looking for.
You can find docs on that here:
https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/inspecting-data-integrated-storage?in=vault/monitoring#secret-engine-data-example

Comment: I was wondering if I can use the golang API to decode it. It seems the tar file does not contain the actual key/value secrets and data. It seems the tar file just contains metadata and not the actual secrets.